# Recent misalignment in activity tabs?

Tags: bug, profile-page

I think there's been a recent misalignment in the activity page of a user's profile? Also, if memory serves me right there used to be slightly more spacing between the blue rectangles and the text?

As in the screenshot:

[image: picture of activity tab in user profile]

Comment: Was literally just about to report this myself.

Comment: @Ollie I've been asking myself for 2 or 3 days: *"Should I post this? Should I not post?..."*

Comment: I always just go right ahead ;)

Comment: It looks like a `display:  flex;` was added in the CSS.  Disable, it's causing the problem.

Comment: If this turns out to be by-design I've got a userscript standing by ;)

Comment: How does this look https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBXP9.png?

Comment: @Ollie the fonts don't look good, the blue box is slightly too low, the numbers themselves are too high and slightly off to the left. (I'm also a vanilla guy...)

Comment: I didn't fiddle with any of those... but I'll see what I can do.  Fonts for all of SE, or just for this?

Comment: @Ollie uuhhh, I don't know...I like looking at design but I don't understand much about it. (The 3 looks ok, but the 5 is slightly too angled at the top part.)

Comment: It's properly spaced now, but the numbers are still too high.

Comment: @Ollie yes I just noticed, we have to wait a while longer but seems to be on the path to getting resolved.